# CMD does not show active users

Tags: jmeter

When i run my jmx file having 1 user using command prompt it shows the response that run ends up and also give the average time etc.

But when i run same jmx with 5 users it does not show how many users are active and also does not give the result.

cmd stop after this line.

> Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default JMeter's [Summariser](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-2-techniques-get-jmeter-test-results-non-gui-mode) reports results in [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) each 30 seconds so probably you didn't wait long enough or your test finished earlier.

[image: JMeter Summariser Default]

If you need more frequent output you can amend **summariser.interval** property (i.e. to occur each 5 seconds) by passing -t via -J command-line argument like:

```
jmeter -Jsummariser.interval=5 -n -t test.jmx -l test.jtl
```

[image: JMeter Summariser 5 seconds]

To make the change permanent just add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
summariser.interval=5
```

See [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) User Manual chapter for more details.